# C# : How to add both scrollbars in a PictureBox contained in a SplitContainer Panel

Tags: c#, scroll, scrollbar, panel, autoscroll

I've found a similar question, but the answer only helps making one of the scrollbars appear.

My form has a SplitContainer. In one of its panels (Panel2) there is a PictureBox with an image i want to show.

What i need is to find a way to make both vertical and horizontal scrollbars appear when the image exceeds the panel's size.

I already set AutoScroll to true, and I've seen it's necessary to set Anchor at left for one of the scrollbars to appear, and at Top for the other one, but i need both of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so set anchor at top and left, and not bottom or right

Answer (score 1):

make sure your SplitContainer.Panel in which you embedded your PictureBox
has AutoScroll property set to True
and your PictureBox has SizeMode property set to 'AutoSize' (PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize).

Hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any issues setting up something like this. Here's my designer code:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).BeginInit();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // splitContainer1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel2
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScroll = true;
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(576, 406);
        this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 192;
        this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Image = global::WinFormsScratch.Properties.Resources.Desert;
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 768);
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(576, 406);
        this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainer1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;





}
```